# Add text on mouse hover on goJS diagram

Tags: javascript, html, mousehover, gojs

I want to create an ER (entity relationship diagram) with JavaScript and [GoJS](https://gojs.net/latest/index.html). I also want when mouse hoovers above a node to show a text with some Info about each node. I tried to use this [example](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/tooltips.html) and here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>ER diagram</title>
<meta name="description" content="Interactive entity-relationship diagram or data model diagram implemented by GoJS in JavaScript for HTML." />
<!-- Copyright 1998-2018 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.8.10/go-debug.js"></script>

<script id="code">
  function init() {

  var $ = go.GraphObject.make;  // for conciseness in defining templates

    myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
        {
          initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Left,
          allowDelete: false,
          allowCopy: false,
          layout: $(go.ForceDirectedLayout),
          "undoManager.isEnabled": true
        });
  
  
 function diagramInfo(model) {
  return "A returned text for dispaly";
 }
   // provide a tooltip for the background of the Diagram, when not over any Part
    myDiagram.toolTip =
    $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
      $(go.Shape, { fill: "#CCFFCC" }),
      $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 4 },
        // use a converter to display information about the diagram model
        new go.Binding("text", "", diagramInfo))
    );

 var nodeHoverAdornment =
      $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
        {
          background: "transparent",
          // hide the Adornment when the mouse leaves it
          mouseLeave: function(e, obj) {
            var ad = obj.part;
            ad.adornedPart.removeAdornment("mouseHover");
          }
        },
  $(go.Placeholder,
          {
            background: "transparent",  // to allow this Placeholder to be "seen" by mouse events
            isActionable: true,  // needed because this is in a temporary Layer
            click: function(e, obj) {
              var node = obj.part.adornedPart;
              node.diagram.select(node);
            }
          })
      );
 
   
    // define several shared Brushes
    var yellowgrad = $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(254, 221, 50)", 1: "rgb(254, 182, 50)" });
    var lightgrad = $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 1: "#E6E6FA", 0: "#FFFAF0" });
 

    // the template for each attribute in a node's array of item data
    var itemTempl =
      $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
        $(go.Shape,
          { desiredSize: new go.Size(10, 10) },
          new go.Binding("figure", "figure"),
          new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          { stroke: "#333333",
            font: "bold 14px sans-serif" },
          new go.Binding("text", "name"))
      );

    // define the Node template, representing an entity
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",  // the whole node panel
        { selectionAdorned: true,
          resizable: true,
          layoutConditions: go.Part.LayoutStandard & ~go.Part.LayoutNodeSized,
          fromSpot: go.Spot.AllSides,
          toSpot: go.Spot.AllSides,
          isShadowed: true,
          shadowColor: "#C5C1AA" },
        new go.Binding("location", "location").makeTwoWay(),
        // whenever the PanelExpanderButton changes the visible property of the "LIST" panel,
        // clear out any desiredSize set by the ResizingTool.
        new go.Binding("desiredSize", "visible", function(v) { return new go.Size(NaN, NaN); }).ofObject("LIST"),
        // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the Table
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
          { fill: lightgrad, stroke: "#756875", strokeWidth: 3 }),
        $(go.Panel, "Table",
          { margin: 8, stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill },
          $(go.RowColumnDefinition, { row: 0, sizing: go.RowColumnDefinition.None }),
          // the table header
          $(go.TextBlock,
            {
              row: 0, alignment: go.Spot.Center,
              margin: new go.Margin(0, 14, 0, 2),  // leave room for Button
              font: "bold 16px sans-serif"
            },
            new go.Binding("text", "key")),
          // the collapse/expand button
          $("PanelExpanderButton", "LIST",  // the name of the element whose visibility this button toggles
            { row: 0, alignment: go.Spot.TopRight }),
          // the list of Panels, each showing an attribute
          $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
            {
              name: "LIST",
              row: 1,
              padding: 3,
              alignment: go.Spot.TopLeft,
              defaultAlignment: go.Spot.Left,
              stretch: go.GraphObject.Horizontal,
              itemTemplate: itemTempl
            },
            new go.Binding("itemArray", "items"))
   ,{
   toolTip:  // define a tooltip for each node that displays the color as text
     $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
    $(go.Shape, { fill: "#FFFFCC" }),
    $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 50 },
      new go.Binding("text", "color"))
     )  // end of Adornment
      }
        )  // end Table Panel
      );
   

    // define the Link template, representing a relationship
    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
      $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
        {
          selectionAdorned: true,
          layerName: "Foreground",
          reshapable: true,
          routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
          corner: 5,
          curve: go.Link.JumpOver
        },
        $(go.Shape,  // the link shape
          { stroke: "#303B45", strokeWidth: 2.5 }),
        $(go.TextBlock,  // the "from" label
          {
            textAlign: "center",
            font: "bold 14px sans-serif",
            stroke: "#1967B3",
            segmentIndex: 0,
            segmentOffset: new go.Point(NaN, NaN),
            segmentOrientation: go.Link.OrientUpright
          },
          new go.Binding("text", "text")),
        $(go.TextBlock,  // the "to" label
          {
            textAlign: "center",
            font: "bold 14px sans-serif",
            stroke: "#1967B3",
            segmentIndex: -1,
            segmentOffset: new go.Point(NaN, NaN),
            segmentOrientation: go.Link.OrientUpright
          },
          new go.Binding("text", "toText"))
      );
   

    // create the model for the E-R diagram
    var nodeDataArray = [
  { key: "tabA",
        items: [ { name: "TabA Key", iskey: true, figure: "Decision", color: 'pink'  } ] },
      { key: "tabB",
        items: [ { name: "TabB Key", iskey: true, figure: "Decision", color: 'pink' },
     { name: "TabB attribute", iskey: true, figure: "Decision", color: 'lightblue' }  ] },
      { key: "tabC",
        items: [ { name: "TabC Key", iskey: true, figure: "Decision", color: 'pink' }] }      
     
    ];

 
 //Options [BpmnEventTimer,BpmnEventConditional,MagneticData,Cube1,Decision,TriangleUp]
    var linkDataArray = [
      { from: "tabA", to: "tabB", text: "1", toText: "1" },
      { from: "tabB", to: "tabC", text: "1", toText: "2" }
    ];
    myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(nodeDataArray, linkDataArray);
   
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="sample">
  <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="background-color: white; border: solid 1px black; width: 50%; height: 600px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see It generates a text box on mouse hoover over a node but it does not display any text. Can anyone help on how to generate text and specifically different text for each node? I want to display a different (predetermined) description for each node in that text.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be using tooltips as the standard mechanism for showing something upon a mouse hover: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/tooltips.html.

In your node template it appears that you have assigned a tooltip to a panel inside your node.  That means it is data bound to the same data that the node is bound to.

However, your binding of `new go.Binding("text", "color")` would imply that there be a "color" property on your node data.  When I look at the node data in the model, there does not seem to be any "color" property on the node.  So the binding is not evaluated.  Since you hadn't assigned an initial value to the **TextBlock.text** property, there's no string to be rendered.

There is such a property on the individual item data, but you didn't assign the tooltip in the itemTemplate.

Comment: One quick question do you think its possible to define two separate tooltips one for node and one for items of the node? I can show messages from either a node tooltip or from a per item tooltip. When I use both only per item shows (I guess it overwrites the per node tootip) I was wondering If could diplay both, for example stacked one on top of the other

Comment: As far as I know, the tooltip mechanisms in all of the window systems that I know of only show one tooltip at a time. That is also true for GoJS.

Answer (score 0):

After the suggestion of Walter Northwoods I added the tooltip in item template and here is the code where each node item has each own descriptive toolip

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>ER diagram</title>
<meta name="description" content="Interactive entity-relationship diagram or data model diagram implemented by GoJS in JavaScript for HTML." />
<!-- Copyright 1998-2018 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.8.10/go-debug.js"></script>

<script id="code">
  function init() {

  var $ = go.GraphObject.make;  // for conciseness in defining templates

    myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
        {
          initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Left,
          allowDelete: false,
          allowCopy: false,
          layout: $(go.ForceDirectedLayout),
          "undoManager.isEnabled": true
        });
  
  
 function diagramInfo(model) {
  return "A returned text for dispaly";
 }
   // provide a tooltip for the background of the Diagram, when not over any Part
    myDiagram.toolTip =
    $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
      $(go.Shape, { fill: "#CCFFCC" }),
      $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 4 },
        // use a converter to display information about the diagram model
        new go.Binding("text", "", diagramInfo))
    );

 var nodeHoverAdornment =
      $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
        {
          background: "transparent",
          // hide the Adornment when the mouse leaves it
          mouseLeave: function(e, obj) {
            var ad = obj.part;
            ad.adornedPart.removeAdornment("mouseHover");
          }
        },
  $(go.Placeholder,
          {
            background: "transparent",  // to allow this Placeholder to be "seen" by mouse events
            isActionable: true,  // needed because this is in a temporary Layer
            click: function(e, obj) {
              var node = obj.part.adornedPart;
              node.diagram.select(node);
            }
          })
      );
 
   
    // define several shared Brushes
    var yellowgrad = $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(254, 221, 50)", 1: "rgb(254, 182, 50)" });
    var lightgrad = $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 1: "#E6E6FA", 0: "#FFFAF0" });
 

    // the template for each attribute in a node's array of item data
    var itemTempl =
      $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
        $(go.Shape,
          { desiredSize: new go.Size(10, 10) },
          new go.Binding("figure", "figure"),
          new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          { stroke: "#333333",
            font: "bold 14px sans-serif" },
          new go.Binding("text", "name")),
 {
    toolTip:  // define a tooltip for each node that displays the color as text
      $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, { fill: "#FFFFCC" }),
        $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 10 },
          new go.Binding("text", "desc"))
      )  // end of Adornment
 }

      );

    // define the Node template, representing an entity
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",  // the whole node panel
        { selectionAdorned: true,
          resizable: true,
          layoutConditions: go.Part.LayoutStandard & ~go.Part.LayoutNodeSized,
          fromSpot: go.Spot.AllSides,
          toSpot: go.Spot.AllSides,
          isShadowed: true,
          shadowColor: "#C5C1AA" },
        new go.Binding("location", "location").makeTwoWay(),
        // whenever the PanelExpanderButton changes the visible property of the "LIST" panel,
        // clear out any desiredSize set by the ResizingTool.
        new go.Binding("desiredSize", "visible", function(v) { return new go.Size(NaN, NaN); }).ofObject("LIST"),
        // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the Table
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
          { fill: lightgrad, stroke: "#756875", strokeWidth: 3 }),
        $(go.Panel, "Table",
          { margin: 8, stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill },
          $(go.RowColumnDefinition, { row: 0, sizing: go.RowColumnDefinition.None }),
          // the table header
          $(go.TextBlock,
            {
              row: 0, alignment: go.Spot.Center,
              margin: new go.Margin(0, 14, 0, 2),  // leave room for Button
              font: "bold 16px sans-serif"
            },
            new go.Binding("text", "key")),
          // the collapse/expand button
          $("PanelExpanderButton", "LIST",  // the name of the element whose visibility this button toggles
            { row: 0, alignment: go.Spot.TopRight }),
          // the list of Panels, each showing an attribute
          $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
            {
              name: "LIST",
              row: 1,
              padding: 3,
              alignment: go.Spot.TopLeft,
              defaultAlignment: go.Spot.Left,
              stretch: go.GraphObject.Horizontal,
              itemTemplate: itemTempl
            },
            new go.Binding("itemArray", "items"))
        )  // end Table Panel
      );
   

    // define the Link template, representing a relationship
    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
      $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
        {
          selectionAdorned: true,
          layerName: "Foreground",
          reshapable: true,
          routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
          corner: 5,
          curve: go.Link.JumpOver
        },
        $(go.Shape,  // the link shape
          { stroke: "#303B45", strokeWidth: 2.5 }),
        $(go.TextBlock,  // the "from" label
          {
            textAlign: "center",
            font: "bold 14px sans-serif",
            stroke: "#1967B3",
            segmentIndex: 0,
            segmentOffset: new go.Point(NaN, NaN),
            segmentOrientation: go.Link.OrientUpright
          },
          new go.Binding("text", "text")),
        $(go.TextBlock,  // the "to" label
          {
            textAlign: "center",
            font: "bold 14px sans-serif",
            stroke: "#1967B3",
            segmentIndex: -1,
            segmentOffset: new go.Point(NaN, NaN),
            segmentOrientation: go.Link.OrientUpright
          },
          new go.Binding("text", "toText"))
      );
   

  // create the model for the E-R diagram
var nodeDataArray = [
 { key: "tabA",
    items: [ { name: "TabA Key", iskey: true, figure: "Decision", color: 'pink' , desc: "Tab A Key is tab A key" } ],
 nodedesc: "Tab A desc" },
  { key: "tabB",
    items: [ { name: "TabB Key", iskey: true, figure: "Decision", color: 'pink', desc: "Tab B Key is tab B key" },
    { name: "TabB attribute", iskey: true, figure: "Decision", color: 'lightblue', desc: "Tab B Attribute is tab B attr" } ],
 nodedesc: "Tab B desc"  },
  { key: "tabC",
    items: [ { name: "TabC Key", iskey: true, figure: "Decision", color: 'pink' , desc: "Tab C Key is tab C key" } ],
 nodedesc : "Tab C desc" }
];

 
 //Options [BpmnEventTimer,BpmnEventConditional,MagneticData,Cube1,Decision,TriangleUp]
    var linkDataArray = [
      { from: "tabA", to: "tabB", text: "1", toText: "1" },
      { from: "tabB", to: "tabC", text: "1", toText: "2" }
    ];
    myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(nodeDataArray, linkDataArray);
   
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="sample">
  <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="background-color: white; border: solid 1px black; width: 50%; height: 600px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

to simplify the answer - you need to add tooltip property to your nodeTemplate and bind data ( in this example im binding to nodeDataArray.key ), analogically to this:

```
yourDiagram.nodeTemplate = go.GraphObject.make(go.Node, 'Spot', 
  {
            toolTip:
                go.GraphObject.make(go.Adornment, "Spot",
                    {
                        background: "transparent"
                    },
                    go.GraphObject.make(go.Placeholder, {
                        padding: 5
                    }),
                    go.GraphObject.make(go.TextBlock,
                        {
                            alignment: go.Spot.Top,
                            alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Bottom,
                            stroke: "#0f1b54",
                            editable: true
                        },
                        new go.Binding("text", "key", function (tooltip_key) {
                            return tooltip_key
                        })),
                )
        },
```